# Showing that $P(\mathbb{R}^n)\cong S(\mathbb{R}^n)$. What is wrong with my argument?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $S(\mathbb{R}^n):=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:|x|=1\}$. Let $P(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be the $n-1$ th projective space. Let $p:\mathbb{R}^n-\{0\}\rightarrow P(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be the map that sends every element to its equivalence class. It is clear that $p$ is an identification map.

Let $q:\mathbb{R}^n-\{0\}\rightarrow S(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be the map that sends $x$ to $\frac{x}{|x|}$. I showed that this map is an identification map. Now consider the function $\lambda:S(\mathbb{R}^{n})\rightarrow P(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ that sends $x$ to the equivalence class of $P(\mathbb{R}^n)$ that contains $x$.I showed that $\lambda$ is a bijection. Moreover, $\lambda q=p$.

It is a fact that if $F:X\rightarrow Y,G:X\rightarrow Z$ are identification maps and $h:Y\rightarrow Z$ is a bijection such that $hF=G$, then $Y\cong Z$. Thus $P(\mathbb{R}^n)\cong S(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Where is the mistake in my argument ?

Thank you

Comment: Your $\lambda$ is not a bijection.

Comment: @StefanH. Why not ?

Comment: Because it identifies two opposite points. It sends $x$ and $-x$ to the same class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $\lambda$ is not a bijection as it sends the points $\frac{x}{|x|}$ and $\frac{-x}{|x|}$ to the same point in $P(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Comment: Thanks +1. This was a bad mistake

Comment: It's not a **bad** mistake. The subtleties of quotient maps can often make the best of us slip up.

Comment: Consider the equivalence relation $\equiv$ on $S(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $x\equiv y$ iff $x=-y$. Let $\gamma:S(\mathbb{R}^n)\rightarrow S(\mathbb{R}^n/\equiv$ be the map that sends every element to its equivalence class.

Comment: Equip $S(\mathbb{R}^n)/\equiv$ with the final topology with respect to $\gamma$. It follows that $\gamma q$ is an identification map. I think that I can repeat the same argument now

Comment: Yes, $S(\mathbb{R}^n)/(x\sim -x)$ is homeomorphic to $P(\mathbb{R}^n)$. In fact, some people take this quotient space to be the definition of the $n$-dimensional real projective space.

Comment: OK. Now my morale is up a little bit!

Answer (score 2):

$\lambda$ is not bijective. It is 2:1, and in fact we have $P(\mathbb{R}^n) = S(\mathbb{R}^n) / C_2$ with the obvious $C_2$-action on the sphere.

Comment: Thanks +1. This was a bad mistake